# Select first drop down and focus

Tags: jquery, html, css

What is the selector for the first select node (drop down)?

This works for first input but I need to find the first select (drop down).

```
$('.modal :input:first').focus();
```

This does not find the dropdown.

```
$('.modal select:first').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
 $("select:first").focus();
```

Comment: TRY THIS 
$('select option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");

Comment: nope. maybe because this is a modal it is not working like it should.

Comment: lemme try something else

Comment: i think the issue was: the bootstrap modal needed a tabindex="-1" of negative 1.

Comment: Ohh you were using bootstrap .. Interesting ..Did it solved the issue??